# Proving a function is a Discrete Probability Mass Function

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

Given this function:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1:givenpdf}
    \mathbb{P}\left[X=\frac{a}{n}\right] = \frac{36}{5}\frac{n^2}{\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)\left(n+3\right)\left(n+4\right)}\ for\ n=1,2,\dots
\end{equation}

I need to find the values that $a$ can take such that it is a valid pmf.

For my solution, I deduced that $a \in \mathbb{R}$ since it is not part of the probability measure.
Now, to check if it is a valid pdf, I am aware that the function has to be non-negative, which in this case is trivial, and I need to show that its sum to infinty is 1.
This last part is where I am having problems. I tried to decompose it by Partial Fractions but every single one diverges.

Is there a way to show that the sum to infinty is 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to show that

$$ \frac {n^2} {(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)} \equiv 
\frac {1} {6} \frac {1} {n+1} - 2 \frac {1} {n+2} 
+ \frac {9} {2} \frac {1} {n+3} - \frac {8} {3} \frac {1} {n+4}$$

Then using the method of difference,

$$ \begin{align} &~ \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac {n^2} {(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)} \\
= &~ \frac {1} {6}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac {1} {n+1} 
- 2 \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac {1} {n+2} 
+ \frac {9} {2} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac {1} {n+3} 
- \frac {8} {3} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac {1} {n+4} \\
= &~ \frac {1} {6}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac {1} {n+1} 
- 2 \sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\frac {1} {n+1} 
+ \frac {9} {2} \sum_{n=3}^{N+2} \frac {1} {n+1} 
- \frac {8} {3} \sum_{n=4}^{N+3} \frac {1} {n+1} \\
= &~ \frac {1} {6} \left(\frac {1} {2} + \frac {1} {3} + \frac {1} {4}\right)
- 2\left(\frac {1} {3} + \frac {1} {4}\right) 
+ \frac {9} {2} \times \frac {1} {4} \\
&~ + \left(\frac {1} {6} - 2 + \frac {9} {2} - \frac {8} {3} \right) \sum_{n=4}^{N} \frac {1} {n+1} \\
&~ - 2 \frac {1} {N+2} + \frac {9} {2} \left(\frac {1} {N+2} + \frac {1} {N+3} \right) - \frac {8} {3}\left(\frac {1} {N+2} + \frac {1} {N+3} + \frac {1} {N+4}\right) \\
= &~ \frac {13} {72} - \frac {7} {6} + \frac {9} {8} 
+ \frac {1 - 12 + 27 - 16} {6} \sum_{n=4}^{N} \frac {1} {n+1} \\
&~ - 2 \frac {1} {N+2} + \frac {9} {2} \left(\frac {1} {N+2} + \frac {1} {N+3} \right) - \frac {8} {3}\left(\frac {1} {N+2} + \frac {1} {N+3} + \frac {1} {N+4}\right) \\ 
= &~ \frac {13 - 84 + 81} {72} + 0 \\
&~ - 2 \frac {1} {N+2} + \frac {9} {2} \left(\frac {1} {N+2} + \frac {1} {N+3} \right) - \frac {8} {3}\left(\frac {1} {N+2} + \frac {1} {N+3} + \frac {1} {N+4}\right) \\ 
= &~ \frac {5} {36} \\
&~ - 2 \frac {1} {N+2} + \frac {9} {2} \left(\frac {1} {N+2} + \frac {1} {N+3} \right) - \frac {8} {3}\left(\frac {1} {N+2} + \frac {1} {N+3} + \frac {1} {N+4}\right) \\ 
\end{align}$$

By letting $N \to +\infty$, all the latter terms vanish and we obtain
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac {n^2} {(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)} = \frac {5} {36} $$

And it shows that the sum to infinity of the given pmf equal to $1$

Please note that it is not rigorous to write
$$ \begin{align} &~ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac {n^2} {(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)} \\
= &~ \frac {1} {6}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac {1} {n+1} 
- 2 \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac {1} {n+2} 
+ \frac {9} {2} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac {1} {n+3} 
- \frac {8} {3} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac {1} {n+4} \end{align} $$

It is tempting to do so but as what you said
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac {1} {n+1} $$
diverge and does not exist.

The identity
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} (x_n + y_n) = \lim_{n\to +\infty}x_n + \lim_{n\to +\infty} y_n$$
require each individual limit of $x_n$ and $y_n$ exist.
If they do not, then we cannot write like this.